# Simplifying gross excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to sum a range of values from an external workbook. The range changes depending on values in the current workbook.

The way I am currently doing it is with this formula:

```
SUM(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'[EXTERNALBOOK.xlsm]Actual'!", ADDRESS(MATCH(F3+1, '[EXTERNALBOOK.xlsm]Actual'!$B$1:$B$378,0), 88), ":", ADDRESS(MATCH(G3, '[EXTERNALBOOK.xlsm]Actual'!$B$1:$B$378,0), 88))))
```

It's very hard to parse and I'm sure it can be greatly simplified. I would be very surprised if this is the 'normal' way to sum an external range.

How it works:

1. First construct the address where the sought values are found. They specifically are dates. ie. we might want the values from then 2nd of November to the 15th, so we build strings representing these cells (eg. $A$37 and $A$50).
2. Concatenate these addresses with the name of the worksheet to produce a valid range ie. output is `'[EXTERNALBOOK.xlsm]Actual'!$A$37:$A$50`
3. Use INDIRECT to convert this back from a string to something we can actually pass to SUM
4. call SUM(*string_built_above*)

Conceptually this isn't that hard to follow, but it's hard to tell that this is what's happening when you look at that big long unformatted excel formula.
Is there a way to simplify this? Am I missing an obvious solution/going the super long way about this?

I appreciate any and all help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should be able to use `sumif` formula to solve this problem.
If you provide the condition to satify to sum the range from other cells, then you don't have to worry about dynamically changing the range for sumation.
the syntax is:

`SUMIF(ConditionRange,Condition,SumRange)`

For more detail [Look Here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b)

Comment: Interestingly, I couldn't get SUMIF to work but SUMIFS did. Bizarre. Thanks though! This is a much neater solution.

Comment: you have `>` and `<` so it should have been sumifs, sumif doesn't take two conditions. Glad you found the solution though.